# AngularJs How to show filter result in Angular UI Bootstrap's pagination

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-filter, angular-ui-pagination

The filter result only shows with in the `numPerPage` result because of **Angular UI Bootstrap**'s **pagination**. Is there any option to show filter result from the `$scope.expenses` as filter result ?

**Demo: http://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/zGbBqR**

```js
angular.module('mytodos', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('TodoController', function($scope) {
  /* paggination */
  if (localStorage.getItem("itemPerPage") === null) {
    localStorage.setItem("itemPerPage", 10);
  }
  function getPerPage(){   
    return parseInt(localStorage.itemPerPage);
  }
  $scope.changeNum = function (itemNum) {
    localStorage.itemPerPage = itemNum;
    $scope.numPerPage = getPerPage();
  };

  console.log(localStorage.itemPerPage);
  $scope.numsForPage = [5, 10, 25, 50, 100];
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.numPerPage = getPerPage();
  $scope.maxSize = 5;
  
  $scope.filteredTodos = [];
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.numPerPage = 10;
  $scope.maxSize = 5;
  $scope.expenses = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Warren Phillips",
      "amount": "37.47",
      "date": "12/11/2015",
      "description": "blandit. Nam nulla magna, malesuada vel, convallis in, cursus et, eros. Proin ultrices. Duis volutpat nunc sit amet metus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisis. Suspendisse commodo tincidunt nibh. Phasellus nulla. Integer vulputate, risus a ultricies adipiscing, enim mi tempor lorem, eget mollis lectus pede et risus. Quisque libero lacus, varius et, euismod et, commodo at, libero. Morbi accumsan"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Declan Ayala",
      "amount": "29.18",
      "date": "12/17/2014",
      "description": "Integer eu lacus. Quisque imperdiet, erat nonummy ultricies ornare, elit elit fermentum risus, at fringilla purus mauris a nunc. In at pede. Cras"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Ivana Bell",
      "amount": "88.53",
      "date": "11/20/2014",
      "description": "Etiam imperdiet dictum magna. Ut tincidunt orci quis lectus. Nullam suscipit, est ac facilisis facilisis, magna tellus faucibus leo, in lobortis tellus justo sit amet nulla."
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Brennan Noel",
      "amount": "17.76",
      "date": "02/06/2015",
      "description": "velit eu sem. Pellentesque ut ipsum ac mi eleifend egestas. Sed pharetra, felis"
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Thomas Tran",
      "amount": "29.59",
      "date": "08/20/2014",
      "description": "nisl sem, consequat nec, mollis vitae, posuere at, velit. Cras lorem lorem, luctus ut, pellentesque eget, dictum placerat, augue. Sed molestie. Sed id risus quis diam luctus lobortis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos hymenaeos. Mauris ut quam vel sapien imperdiet ornare."
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Tucker Bolton",
      "amount": "66.69",
      "date": "12/09/2014",
      "description": "et risus. Quisque libero lacus, varius et, euismod et, commodo at, libero. Morbi accumsan laoreet ipsum. Curabitur consequat, lectus sit amet luctus vulputate, nisi sem semper erat, in consectetuer ipsum nunc id enim. Curabitur massa. Vestibulum accumsan neque et nunc. Quisque ornare tortor at risus. Nunc ac sem ut dolor dapibus gravida. Aliquam tincidunt, nunc ac mattis ornare, lectus ante dictum mi, ac mattis velit justo nec ante. Maecenas mi felis, adipiscing fringilla, porttitor vulputate, posuere vulputate, lacus. Cras interdum."
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Medge Mullen",
      "amount": "23.78",
      "date": "10/17/2015",
      "description": "dictum mi, ac mattis velit justo nec ante. Maecenas mi felis, adipiscing fringilla, porttitor vulputate, posuere vulputate, lacus. Cras interdum. Nunc sollicitudin commodo ipsum. Suspendisse non leo. Vivamus nibh dolor, nonummy ac, feugiat non, lobortis quis, pede. Suspendisse dui. Fusce diam nunc, ullamcorper eu, euismod ac, fermentum vel, mauris. Integer sem elit, pharetra ut, pharetra sed, hendrerit a, arcu. Sed et"
    }, {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "Morgan Merritt",
      "amount": "54.09",
      "date": "04/10/2016",
      "description": "Nulla facilisis. Suspendisse commodo tincidunt nibh. Phasellus nulla. Integer vulputate, risus a ultricies adipiscing, enim mi tempor lorem, eget mollis lectus pede et risus. Quisque libero lacus, varius et, euismod et,"
    }, {
      "id": 9,
      "name": "Janna Casey",
      "amount": "22.61",
      "date": "08/05/2015",
      "description": "eros turpis non enim. Mauris quis turpis vitae purus gravida sagittis. Duis gravida. Praesent eu nulla at sem molestie sodales. Mauris blandit enim consequat purus. Maecenas libero est, congue a, aliquet vel, vulputate eu, odio. Phasellus at augue id ante dictum"
    }, {
      "id": 10,
      "name": "Buffy Best",
      "amount": "59.98",
      "date": "05/06/2015",
      "description": "lacus vestibulum lorem, sit amet ultricies sem magna nec quam. Curabitur vel lectus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec dignissim magna a tortor. Nunc commodo auctor velit. Aliquam nisl. Nulla eu neque pellentesque massa lobortis ultrices. Vivamus rhoncus. Donec est. Nunc ullamcorper, velit in aliquet lobortis, nisi nibh lacinia orci, consectetuer euismod est arcu ac orci. Ut semper pretium neque. Morbi quis urna."
    }, {
      "id": 11,
      "name": "Brielle Newman",
      "amount": "52.26",
      "date": "04/16/2016",
      "description": "placerat, augue. Sed molestie. Sed id risus quis diam luctus lobortis."
    }, {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Julie James",
      "amount": "6.38",
      "date": "08/15/2014",
      "description": "placerat, orci lacus vestibulum lorem, sit amet ultricies sem magna nec quam. Curabitur vel lectus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec dignissim magna a tortor. Nunc commodo auctor velit. Aliquam nisl. Nulla eu neque"
    }, {
      "id": 13,
      "name": "Shaine Barnett",
      "amount": "0.04",
      "date": "09/29/2014",
      "description": "laoreet, libero et tristique pellentesque, tellus sem mollis dui, in sodales elit erat vitae risus. Duis a mi fringilla mi lacinia mattis. Integer eu lacus. Quisque imperdiet, erat nonummy ultricies ornare, elit elit fermentum risus, at fringilla purus mauris a nunc. In at pede. Cras vulputate velit eu sem. Pellentesque ut ipsum ac mi eleifend egestas. Sed"
    }, {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Genevieve Underwood",
      "amount": "50.71",
      "date": "09/24/2015",
      "description": "consequat auctor, nunc nulla vulputate dui, nec tempus mauris erat eget ipsum. Suspendisse sagittis. Nullam vitae diam. Proin dolor. Nulla semper"
    }, {
      "id": 15,
      "name": "Adam Villarreal",
      "amount": "18.48",
      "date": "04/06/2016",
      "description": "nisl. Maecenas malesuada fringilla est. Mauris eu turpis. Nulla aliquet. Proin velit. Sed malesuada augue ut lacus. Nulla tincidunt, neque vitae semper egestas, urna justo faucibus lectus, a sollicitudin orci sem eget massa. Suspendisse eleifend. Cras sed leo. Cras vehicula aliquet libero. Integer in magna. Phasellus dolor elit, pellentesque a, facilisis non, bibendum sed, est. Nunc laoreet lectus quis massa. Mauris"
    }
  ];
}).filter('pagination', function() {
   return function(input, currentPage, pageSize) {
     if(angular.isArray(input)) {
       var start = (currentPage-1)*pageSize;
       var end = currentPage*pageSize;
       return input.slice(start, end);
     }
   };
 });
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #DDD;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.tab-content > .tab-pane > .box {
  border-top: none;
}
.tab-content > .box {
  border-top: none;
}
select.pagiantion{
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mytodos" ng-controller="TodoController">
  <div class="container">
    <hr />
    <tabset>
      <tab>
        <tab-heading>Statement</tab-heading>
        <div class="box">
          <h1>Todos</h1>
          <h4>{{expenses.length}} total</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="">Show 
            <select class="form-control pagiantion" ng-model="numPerPage" ng-options="numPage for numPage in numsForPage" ng-change="changeNum(numPerPage);"></select>
            entries
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
          <div class="form-inline form-group">
            <label for="filter-list">Search </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter-list" placeholder="Search" ng-model="filterlist">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="expense in expenses | pagination: currentPage : numPerPage | filter:filterlist">
            <td>{{expense.name}}</td>
            <td>{{expense.amount}}</td>
            <td>{{expense.date}}</td>
            <td>
              <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" role="group" ng-init="editmode=false">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="editExpense(expense);">
                  <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="deleteExpense(expense); editmode = !editmode">
                  <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="clearfix" ng-show="expenses.length > numPerPage">
        <pagination 
          ng-model="currentPage" 
          total-items="expenses.length" 
          max-size="maxSize" 
          items-per-page="numPerPage"
          boundary-links="true" 
          class="pagination-sm pull-right" 
          previous-text="&lsaquo;" 
          next-text="&rsaquo;" 
          first-text="&laquo;" 
          last-text="&raquo;"
        ></pagination>
      </div>
          
          
        </div>
      </tab>
    </tabset>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to store a filtered list in a variable then use it length to make pagination.

**HTML**

Table tr area.

```
<tr ng-repeat="expense in filteredlist = (expenses | filter:filterlist) |pagination: currentPage : numPerPage">
```

And in **pagination**

```
<pagination 
          ng-model="currentPage" 
          total-items="filteredlist.length" 
          max-size="maxSize" 
          items-per-page="numPerPage"
          boundary-links="true" 
          class="pagination-sm pull-right" 
          previous-text="&lsaquo;" 
          next-text="&rsaquo;" 
          first-text="&laquo;" 
          last-text="&raquo;"
        ></pagination>
```

Then add filteredlist variable in $scope. Initially just copy entire expense to this variable.

**JS**

```
$scope.filteredlist =$scope.expenses;
```

Your fixed [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGPKYE?editors=101)

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of your filters like:

```
expense in expenses | filter:filterlist | pagination: currentPage : numPerPage
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It gives the same result :(

Comment: So you want to be on page 1 and filter results that are in different pages, isn't that it? if so, mine is working as above. http://imgur.com/TG2MtAm this guy was on the third page here

Comment: I have just updated the question with added result of your solution in image. Hope you could understand what I am looking for

Comment: Muhammed, I believe there are quite a few ways to change that, one for example is counting the number of filtered results with 
`<tr ng-repeat="expense in count = ( expenses | filter:filterlist | pagination: currentPage : numPerPage )">` and then using count.length as `total-items` in your `<pagination>` . Just be aware that not always the `count.length` will be the total length, so you will have to switch between total length of expenses and count

Comment: The filter works very well with your solution, at the same time  pagination numbers still the  same.

Comment: The thing is that you filtering solution works fine but unfortunately count doesn't go back when clear `ng-model="filterlist"`

Comment: I see. What if you create a var for total-items and then watch your filterlist. If it is empty you set your var to expenses.length, if not, count.lenght

Comment: the the bracket should be only for `(expenses | filter:filterlist )`